# Is 批判 or 批评 better in 别人总是批判我?

Tags: word-choice

I wrote this:

> 现在我觉得伊斯兰规矩太多了，别人总是批判我。
>   I currently feel like Islam has too many rules, other people are always criticizing me.

My teacher and I had a somewhat long discussion as to whether it should say [批判](http://youdao.com/w/%E6%89%B9%E5%88%A4) (pīpàn) or [批评](http://youdao.com/w/%E6%89%B9%E8%AF%84) (pīpíng) which both translate to "criticize".  We didn't come to a concrete conclusion; she seemed to indicate it depends on the situation.

Basically, I'm expressing my frustration at the large number of rules of Islam, or perhaps more precisely, the large number of rules people think are part of Islam (which may or may not actually be part of Islam).  Other Muslims, in an attempt to help me, criticize me in various ways (e.g., how I'm praying, how I'm eating) and this is what I'm referring to.

**Question**: Is 批判 or 批评 better in 别人总是批判我?

Comment: Perhaps 纠正 would be a better fit on the whole. People are not just expressing their criticisms of you (I’m assuming) but they’re trying to *correct* you. No?

Comment: Generally 批判 is a movement many people take part in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

批判 is to criticize in a **formal, comprehensive** way. E.g. 对于传统文化我们要批判继承. (批评 isn't fit)

批评 is **casual and specific**. E.g. 老师总批评我上课不认真听课. (批判 isn't fit)

If those criticisms are casual, specific, and not that serious in your case, you should use 批评. I don't expect "how I'm praying, how I'm eating" deserves a comprehensive one. They might just criticize for your certain behavior and try to correct you. In this case, 批评(criticize)和指正(correct) are the words you could use.

If you find those criticisms annoying, you could use 指手画脚, 评头论足, and etc.

**P.S.** Colloquially, you can say for your situation: 现在我觉得伊斯兰规矩太多了，经常有人说我这不对那不对的。(烦死了！)

Answer (score 1):

> 批 = criticize; to judge
>
> 判 = to judge
>
> 评 = to comment

批判 means "to criticize (and judge)" of person or people

批评 means "to criticize (and comment)" of anyone or anything

批判 comes from people who are in the position of passing judgement to the one being criticized; while 批评 can come from anyone in whatever position.

A common citizen can 批评 his government, he can also 批评 Apple AirPod Pro being too expensive, but he cannot 批判 his government (he is not in the position to) or AirPod Pro (not human)

So who is in the position of 批判 you? The most common answer is "the public" (or the medias)

批判 (criticize and judge) is a very formal and serious attack on someone, while 批评 (criticize and comment) can be a very minor complain (but it can also be a serious one)

> Question: Is 批判 or 批评 better in 别人总是批判我?

If 别人 is referring to the public or an entire group that passing judgement on you, then 批判 is correct (in this case, 人們 is more specific than 别人)

If 别人 is referring to a few people who complain, then 批评 is correct